# Scatter plots in R. Why am I getting boxes around certain points?

Tags: r, scatter-plot, graphing

Apologies, this is probably the simplest question. I'm having trouble making a scatterplot in R Studio. I am trying to see if amphipod counts are correlated to oxygen content. Whenever I plot this using:

```
    plot(Amphipod~Oxygen...ml.l.)
```

I get a graph with boxes around certain points and I have no idea why. Only 5 points and I can't see anything different about those.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It's hard to help if we can't see what you're looking at exactly.

Comment: Sorry! I added a link

Comment: It looks like your x-axis variable is actually a factor. You are plotting a box and whisker plot, not a true scatter plot. Double check your data types and try again.

Comment: Thanks! Turned out I had one value that was a word